# First time running Python and struggling hard

Tags: python

My intend is make a Subtitle which i need for a Video.
I came across a Website where someone mentioned how i can become a cleaned text from a vtt File.

Here is the Method:

```
youtube-dl --write-auto-sub --convert-subs=srt --skip-download URL
```

For example you are downloading https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=example. with title "example" --convert=srt will output to a file named example.en.srt where en stands for English es for Spanish etc.

The file will have something like this:

00:00:04.259 --> 00:00:05.259
>> I’m Elon Musk.

00:00:05.259 --> 00:00:06.669
>> What is your claim to fame?

00:00:06.669 --> 00:00:07.669
>> I’m the founder of

00:00:07.669 --> 00:00:08.669
Tesla.com.

OPTIONAL - If you need the text to be cleaned up you can use python to clean it a little:

```
    import re
    bad_words = ['-->','</c>'] 
    
    
    with open('example.en.vtt') as oldfile, open('newfile.txt', 'w') as newfile:
        for line in oldfile:
            if not any(bad_word in line for bad_word in bad_words):
                newfile.write(line)
    
    
    with open('newfile.txt') as result:
        uniqlines = set(result.readlines())
        with open('sub_out.txt', 'w') as rmdup:
            mylst = map(lambda each: each.strip("&gt;&gt;"), uniqlines)
            print(mylst)
            rmdup.writelines(set(mylst))
```

Output newfile.txt:

I’m Elon Musk.
What is your claim to fame?
I’m the founder of
Tesla.com.

Ok then I downloaded Python typed `py` in CMD and it runs.

The file is on C Drive under documents and i changed the Filename as same as above and i hope that´s the correct Filename example.en.vtt

then I typed this in cmd

```
f = open("C:\\dokumente\example.en.vtt" , "r" print(f.read())
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

what i´m doing wrong here? I hope someone can help. Thank you

Comment: Put an r before strings with paths: r”C:\somepath”  - this is known as raw strings, will not try to interpret \ as an escape character

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre], and keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**. This question boils down to a simple typo - `open("C:\\dokumente\example.en.vtt" , "r"` is missing the closing `)`. For future questions, please [try to look for such problems](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) yourself before posting, which starts with reading and trying to understand error messages (see how it says `SyntaxError`? see where the `^^^` are pointing?).

Comment: (Also, `print(f.read())` should be on a separate line.)

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open("C:\\dokumente\\example.en.vtt" , "r")  # Properly escaped \ and closing paren
```

Or

```
# f = open("C:/dokumente/exapmle.en.vtt", "r")  # / rather than \
```

Then

```
print(f.read()) # On a different line, or separated with ;
```